# How to filter a String date range from an arrayList using filter() in Java?

Tags: java, string, date, filter, lambda

I am trying to filter records from a `List<People>` based on date range which are stored as `Strings`.

`List` (showing 3 entries only):

```
[["Steve","Baseball","Brazil","August 14, 2020"], ["Ammie","Basketball","Malaysia","September 8, 2021"], ["Tom","Cricket","UK","December 1, 2020"]]
```

How can I filter all records between `startDate (String): August 14, 2020` to `endDate (String): September 8, 2020`?

Currently I am doing this but it's not getting the range values. It only matches either the start date or the end date which isn't what I want.

```
return people.stream().filter(t -> {
       return t.getType().equals(type) && 
           (t.getDateAdded().equals(startDate) ||
                 t.getDateAdded().equals(endDate));
       }
).limit(numberOfRecords).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is the `dateAdded` property of `People` a type `String`? Change that to a `LocalDate`.

Change `startDate` and `endDate` to `LocalDate` too.

Then do:

```java
filter(t -> t.getType().equals(type)
         && t.getDateAdded().compareTo(startDate) >= 0
         && t.getDateAdded().compareTo(endDate) <= 0)
```

Comment: Can I convert to a  `Date` object like this: `DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);  Date date = format.parse(dateAdded); ` ?

Comment: @salazarin You can, but you should not. The classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Use `LocalDate` as shown in the answer and also `DateTimeFormatter`, also from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. sure will keep that in mind. Thank you